# Update Label in PysimpleGUI not Happening

Tags: python, label, pysimplegui

I am trying to update a Label in PySimpleGUI but it is not updating

Kindly advise what I am doing wrong

I am on Windows 10 Computer

```py
    while True:
    event, values = Sample__Window__Layout.read()
    if event in('Exit', None):
        break
    if event == '-File-':
        Excel__Ki__Gatha = Pawan__Simple__GUI.popup_get_file("Take us to the Selected Excel File", title = "Take us to the Selected Excel File", multiple_files = False, file_types = (('Excel Files', '*.xlsx'),), no_window = False, show_hidden = True)
        Gyan__Ganga = values['-Columns-']
        if Excel__Ki__Gatha != "":
            if Gyan__Ganga == "": Gyan__Ganga ='A'
            sleep(1)
            Sample__Window__Layout['-Banana-'].update("Processing Please Wait")
            sleep(1)
            Read__From__Provided__Excel(Excel__Ki__Gatha,Gyan__Ganga)
            break
```

Comment: GUI will be updated until next `sg.Window.read()`. To update immediately, try to call `sg.Window.refresh()` right after you update the label.

Comment: Thank you very much Jason Yang ..... Now it is working ..... I appreciate your help .... Thanks a lot

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.